# Searching for a string that begins with X & Y returns 0 Results MySQL

Tags: mysql

QUERY:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE SomeCol LIKE '%X & Y%'
```

returns no results even though my table contains a row whose `SomeCol = 'X & Y Some More Text'`

If i just search for `'%Z & J%'` returns 1 row but in that record `SomeCol = 'Some Preceeding Text Z & J'`

So basically it returns 0 rows if the ampersand is in the beginning of the string with space but returns correct rows if its in the middle or at the end.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**NOTE:** please note that `%X & Y%` is just one searching string, there could be other strings that my code searches for such as plain string `'%some text%'`

Comment: If `X & Y` is always at the start then you can use `WHERE SomeCol LIKE 'X & Y%'`

Comment: no its not always at start it can be anywhere

Comment: `SELECT 'X & Y Some More Text' LIKE '%X & Y%'` returns `1` for me, are you sure there aren't any problems e.g. with encoding of the characters or some other code?

Comment: Perhaps the spaces are encoded differently, try `LIKE '%X_&_Y%` (`_` means "any single character")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

1) your search string 'X & Y' contains a different number of spaces between the ampersand and the letters than your database does.

2) something's going on about encoding your text strings in the data base (or in your search terms) and the data actually say  `X &amp; Y` rather than `X & Y`. It's common to encode the ampersand in HTML pages.

Note that `column LIKE '%search-term%'` is going to perform hideously badly. That kind of search can never use an index.  You may want to investigate full-text searching if this project is intended to scale up.

Comment: thank you, the problem was with X &amp; Y. is there a way on MySQL search side to convert any html encoded back to its normal form?

Comment: MySQL doesn't encode your data automatically. It's probably your application software doing that. The trick is to encode your search terms the same way your software encodes data on its way into the database.  MySQL doesn't do that but your application can.

Comment: got it, will take a look at it. I think i have an idea where the glitch could be. thanks again